# update-grub/os-loader doesn't see multiple Ubuntu installations on software Raid

Tags: ubuntu, grub, raid, mdadm

I have two disks containing multiple software RAID1 (mdadm) partitions . I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md2` (corresponding to `/boot` and `/`, respectively) and Ubuntu 16.04 on `/dev/md1` and `/dev/md3`. When I ran `update-grub` on either of the two, the other installation could not be detected. I don't want to create a manual menuentry under grub, because that means every time the kernel is upgraded for the other installation, I will have to manually edit the menuentry. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks